# getting wrong output in atmega16

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, atmel

I am trying to build an automatic plant watering system using ATmega16.The logic is, the sensor will give an analog input at PA0 which will be compared with a preset value to turn on/off water pump.

The following is the code fragment we used:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
int adc(void);
void pump(void);
int adc_value;
int main(void)
 {
  DDRC=0x01;                          //Defining PC0 as output
  ADCSRA=0x87;                    //Setting the mode of operation
  ADMUX=0x00;                     //Selection of channel and bit alignment
  while(1)
   {
     adc_value=adc();                //reading moisture level
     pump();                               //Pump activator routine
   }
   return 0;
 }

int adc(void)
{
   int lower_bits,higher_bits,result; 
   ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC)|(1 << ADIF);  //Turn on conversion and clear flag
   while(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF) == 0);  //wait for flag
   lower_bits=ADCL;
   higher_bits=ADCH;
   result=lower_bits|(higher_bits<<8);         //Accessing converted value by shifting
   return result;
 }

void pump(void)
 {
  if(adc_value>=700)                                //Pump ON trigger point
   {
     PORTC|=(1<<0);
   }
  else if(adc_value<=600)                        //Pump Off trigger point
   {
     PORTC&=~(1<<0);
   }
 }
```

Is there anything wrong in the code? Because after burning it, i am getting  low voltage**(0.15**) for wet soil and high voltage(4.84) for dry soil from the analog sensor input which is ok … but the problem is, I am **always** getting voltage like **0.7** (and sometimes like  0.15) at PC0  in both cases(I am using multimeter for measuring this). There in no change in the values for dry and wet soil at PC0.. in such case where is the actual problem? Is there anything wrong in the circuit design or in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected AREF to 5V? The wiring schematic from your other similar post doesn't show it.

As a side note, you might consider using ADLAR, aligning left. Then you only have to look at one byte, since you don't seem to concerned about 10 bits of precision anyway.

Comment: I  haven't made the AREF connected to 5V. Is it mandatory? And one more thing, I haven't understood the line "As a side note, you might consider using ADLAR, aligning left. Then you only have to look at one byte, since you don't seem to concerned about 10 bits of precision anyway"- Will you please clarify this? @UncleO

Comment: @user3114849 The reason I ask about AREF is that you have selected that option in the ADMUX register, REFS1=REFS0=0. If you want to use AVCC, then you need to choose `01` for these bits, and attach a capacitor to AREF.

Comment: @user3114849 Setting the ADLAR bit to one left aligns the 10-bit ADC result in ADCH and ADCL. If you don't care whether you have 8 or 10 bit precision, then you can set ADLAR in ADMUX and read only ADCH to get a value from 0 to 255, where 255 is for V reaching AVCC (or AREF or 2.56 V, depending on which comparison source you chose in ADMUX). Then you could test for `ADCH>=175` and `ADCH<=150`, ignoring the 2 LSBs in ADCL.

Comment: I have selected ADMUX=0x00. In this case will I have to connect the AREF to 5V? or something else? @UncleO

Comment: @user3114849 Perhaps the option you want is to set ADMUX to 0x40 (or 0x60 with ADLAR) and connect a capacitor from AREF to GND (or just leave it unconnected and accept a little noise). What is the output range of the sensor? 0 to 5V = AVCC? Then AVCC is a good choice for the reference. The AREF pin is mostly used in situations you don't seem to be using in your application.